# Permission differences between windows service and console application

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services, permissions, windows-server-2003

I'm developing an application with a smart card involved (digital signature). Let's assume that we have the same code in this two contexts:

- Console application, executed by Administrator user
- Windows Service, executed by Administrator user

I suposed that if this two codes were executed by the same user they would have the same privileges. It seems that this is not true. When I try with the Windows Service (Executed with Administrator user) i receive

```
TargetInvocationException
CryptographicException

Can't initialize DLL provider at System.Security.Cryptography.Utils.CreateProvHandle(.
```

As far as I read on internet maybe is some king of permissions issue. Console Application works OK.

- What is the difference between the Windows Service and Console Application if they are executed by the same user?
- Is possible to achieve the same results with Windows Service?

Free virtual beers for the person who solves it ;)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried running your service as Local Service, Network Service, and Local System? No difference with changing these? I know I had to change mine from Local Service to Local System to give it access to my files. Not sure if you're even using any files, but at least it's something to check.

Comment: Ok, thanks Brandi, that worked!! :). The problem is that I don't know why. I changed to other user because Network service doesn't had access to the certificate. In some way I don't understand, the certificate has ended in the folder:

 - c:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile\application data\microsoft\systemcertificates\my\certificates

Like this file is located in that folder it can work with Local Service and I don't get the error:

 - Can't initialize DLL provider at System.Security.Cryptography.Utils.CreateProvHandle(.

Somebody knows how this file ended in that folder?

Thanks Brandi!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a solution for you, unfortunately, but Windows Services do behave quite differently from ordinary programs. For example, you won't be able to access network drives from a windows service, unless your service starts AFTER the service that initializes those drives.

You can add dependencies to your service, to make them depend on the services you need, or at the very end. This MAY solve your problem, but I cannot guarantee that.

Comment: Thanks Callash, Thanks a lot. Unfortunately my service is starting manually, so all possible dependencies are resolved before.

Comment: If you always start your service manually, what is the point of having it as a windows service in the first place, if you do not mind my asking?

Comment: Yeah, good question ;). I'm starting manually the service just for testing purposes. In production server it has to be started automatically :) .

Comment: Then the only other solution I can come up with, is to create a separate AppDomain and handle the security yourself. But I am no expert on that, I think you will want to google that.

Comment: Thanks Callash, but no way. I've managed to install .Net Framework 2.0  Configuration Tool and I granted to all code groups to 'Full Trust'. But this is not working... I don't know what to look at...

Comment: Creating an AppDomain is done in your code, not with any configuration tool.

Comment: Yes, I know. What I've tried is to modify the permissions of the default AppDomain where all applications are executed. All the code zones are set to 'full trust'

Answer (score 0):

One difference between a console app and a Windows service which caused me headaches is the fact that the Windows service uses **C:\Windows\System32** as the current directory. I don't know if this will help in your case, but I guess you could try it: http://igorbrejc.net/development/c/windows-services-and-working-directories

Comment: Can you post the whole exception description (including the stack trace)?